# Leave blocks of 1 of size >= k in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to leave block >= k of '1'. All other block of '1' should be transformed to zero. For example, **k=2**:

```
df= 
    a  b
0   1  1
1   1  1
2   0  0
3   1  0
4   0  0
5   1  0
6   0  0
7   1  0
8   0  0
9   1  1
10  1  1
11  1  1
12  0  0
13  0  0
14  1  0
15  0  0
16  1  1
17  1  1
18  0  0
19  1  0
```

where the column `a` is the original sequence, and the column `b` is the desired.

Comment: Can you show with k=3?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, for k=3, all rows in column `b` will be zero except [9,10,11]

Comment: That's what I expected. Just checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
z = df.a.eq(0)
g = z.cumsum().mask(z, -1)

k = 2
df['b'] = df.a.groupby(g).transform('size').ge(k).mask(z, 0)

    a  b
0   1  1
1   1  1
2   0  0
3   1  0
4   0  0
5   1  0
6   0  0
7   1  0
8   0  0
9   1  1
10  1  1
11  1  1
12  0  0
13  0  0
14  1  0
15  0  0
16  1  1
17  1  1
18  0  0
19  1  0
```

Comment: @Thanks, great! Where is the parameter k?

Comment: I think technically the parameter in gt should be (k-1) as requested by the OP.

Comment: @DrTRD thanks, i've updated my post to better reflect what OP was doing.