# Detect user churn from first day of activity

Tags: python, pandas

Inspired by [count-consecutive-ones-in-a-dataframe-and-get-indices-where-this-occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986045/count-consecutive-ones-in-a-dataframe-and-get-indices-where-this-occurs), I would like to do something a bit different.

For this DataFrame, `id` is the index.

```
id  day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    day6                                                                                        
1   24      0       0       0       0       0
2   15      0       3       0       0       0
3   9       0       0       0       0       0
4   20      1       0       0       0       0
5   4       0       0       0       0       0
6   3       0       0       1       3       0
7   3       0       0       0       0       0
8   8       0       0       0       2       0
9   8       0       2       0       0       0
10  0       5       2       0       0       0
```

I would like to count how many `id` (user), after x number of days of zero activity, will not have any activities anymore.

For a given function `f(x)`, and assuming `day6` is the last day,

`f(2)` should return `8`, since `id` `[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10]` become churn after 2 consecutive 0.

`f(4)` should return `5`, since `id` `[1,3,4,5,7]` have no activity after 4 consecutive zeros.

I believe the implementation should be `df.apply(f(x), axis=1)`, so it iterates on each row and returns a `1 else 0` column. For instance `df['churn=4'] = df.apply(f(x), axis=1)` shall return:

```
id  day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    day6    'churn=4'                                                                                   
1   24      0       0       0       0       0       1
2   15      0       3       0       0       0       0
3   9       0       0       0       0       0       1
4   20      1       0       0       0       0       1
5   4       0       0       0       0       0       1
6   3       0       0       1       3       0       0
7   3       0       0       0       0       0       1
8   8       0       0       0       2       0       0
9   8       0       2       0       0       0       0
10  0       5       2       0       0       0       0
```

So I can sum up the new column to get the total number of churn=4' users.

I got a bit complicated by myself even when drafting the question, please let me know if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

concat the values, cast it to integer, and then count the last zero.

```
import numpy as np
```

#### **without a function**:

```
np.logical_not(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1).astype(int) % 10**4).astype(int)
```

- where `10**4` means 4 zero.

#### with a function:

```
def f(x, num):
    return np.logical_not(int(''.join(x[1:].astype(str)))% 10**num).astype(int)

df.apply(f, num=4, axis=1)
```

output:

```
Out[181]: 
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    0
dtype: int64
```