# Pandas dataframe rolling consecutive count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, rolling-computation

Suppose, I have Pandas DataFrame look like below:

```
  account   have  
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         2     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1
```

I want the results look like below:

```
  account   want  
  A         NaN   
  A         NaN   
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         3     
  A         3     
  A         3     
  A         3     
  A         3     
  B         NaN   
  B         NaN   
  B         3     
  B         2     
  B         1     
  B         2     
  B         3     
  B         3     
  B         3     
  B         3
```

The idea behind is that given the rolling window equal to `3`. I want to find the longest consecutive count that value equal to `1`. For example, in account `A`, the longest consecutive count that value equal to `1` given window equal to `3` is `1` (at index `2`). At index `3`, the result returns `2` that because given window contained values of `2, 1, 1`.

Follow the same logic above and applied to account B, the results will be as shown.

Any suggestion on this process.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain a bit better why at index 2 the count is 1?

Comment: Because the longest consecutive count value of 1 is only 1. Given rolling window is 3, it then contained value of [1, 2, 1]. So, there is no consecutive value in the window here, it then return the longest consecutive count available, which is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
f = lambda x: 1 if x.iat[1] != 1 else (x == 1).sum()
df['new']=df.groupby('account')['have'].rolling(3).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   account  have  new
0        A     1  NaN
1        A     2  NaN
2        A     1  1.0
3        A     1  2.0
4        A     1  3.0
5        A     1  3.0
6        A     1  3.0
7        A     1  3.0
8        A     1  3.0
9        B     1  NaN
10       B     1  NaN
11       B     1  3.0
12       B     2  2.0
13       B     1  1.0
14       B     1  2.0
15       B     1  3.0
16       B     1  3.0
17       B     1  3.0
18       B     1  3.0
```

Comment: I have a very similar idea but I found it is super slow when applying when a million rows of data.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - ya, agree I got one idea, need some time

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - I think if working with `million rows of data. ` then need pure numpy or numba solution instead `.rolling` function (because slow)

Comment: Any suggestion by using numpy or numba?

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - I try something and failed :( Unfortuantely.

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - btw, how many groups is in `million rows of data`, e.g. in 10**6 rows?

Comment: somethings around 80k

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha - and need rolling by `3` ? Or general solution from rolling by 3,5,10 ?

Comment: Actually, there are lots of condition. The window could be 3, 6, 9, 12 and value could be equal to 1 or greater than 1 and ect.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be:

```
import numpy as np


def compute_max_run(window):
    """Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986888/4001592"""
    diffs = np.diff(window, prepend=0, append=0)

    starts, = np.where(diffs == -1)
    ends, = np.where(diffs == 1)

    if len(ends) and len(starts):
        return (starts - ends).max()
    return 0


def compute(s, w=3, val=1):
    return s.eq(val).rolling(w).apply(compute_max_run)


df['want'] = df.groupby('account')['have'].transform(compute)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   account  have  want
0        A     1   NaN
1        A     2   NaN
2        A     1   1.0
3        A     1   2.0
4        A     1   3.0
5        A     1   3.0
6        A     1   3.0
7        A     1   3.0
8        A     1   3.0
9        B     1   NaN
10       B     1   NaN
11       B     1   3.0
12       B     2   2.0
13       B     1   1.0
14       B     1   2.0
15       B     1   3.0
16       B     1   3.0
17       B     1   3.0
18       B     1   3.0
```

Comment: Getting the error zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha With the same input?

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha Updated the answer.

Comment: It works but I am trying apply to my dataset which has a million of rows, it sees to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
df1.assign(want=df1.groupby('account').rolling(3)
           .apply(lambda ss:ss.diff().eq(0).sum()+1).droplevel(0))
```

out：

```
account  have  want
0        A     1   NaN
1        A     2   NaN
2        A     1   1.0
3        A     1   2.0
4        A     1   3.0
5        A     1   3.0
6        A     1   3.0
7        A     1   3.0
8        A     1   3.0
9        B     1   NaN
10       B     1   NaN
11       B     1   3.0
12       B     2   2.0
```

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha